# Spectrum of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]^{\mathbb{C}^*}$

Tags: commutative-algebra, invariant-theory

Let $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ the ring of polynomials with $\mathbb{C}$-coefficients. We can define an action $\phi: \mathbb{C}^* \times \mathbb{C}[x,y] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ such that $\phi(\lambda,p(x,y))=p(\lambda x,\lambda^{-1}y)$. I have to calculate $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[x,y]^{\mathbb{C}^*})$, i.e. the prime ideals of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ invariant for the action of $\mathbb{C}^*$.

Comment: Are you looking for the prime ideals in the ring of polynomials invariant under the action, which the notation suggests, or really for the prime ideals invariant under the action? I'm not sure if these two are the same although it very well might be true.

Comment: @Piotr: Actually it's vice versa, in good situations $\mathrm{Spec}(A^G) = \mathrm{Spec}(A)/G$ (not $\mathrm{Spec}(A)^G$). See Mumford's *GIT*. But I think ArthurStuart wants to know $\mathrm{Spec}(A^G)$ for $A=k[x,y]$ and $G=k^*$. Greetings to Bonn.

Comment: Yes... thank you Martin

Answer (score 1):

As Piotr and Martin point out in the comments, I think you're actually looking for the prime ideals *of the invariant ring*, not the prime ideals of the original ring that are fixed by the action.

If this is right, the first step is to identify the invariant ring.

A polynomial is invariant under $p(x,y)\mapsto p(\lambda x,\lambda^{-1}y)$ if and only if $x$ and $y$ occur to the same power in every term. Thus the invariants are actually the set of polynomials in $xy$. This ring is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[x]$ so the $\operatorname{Spec}$ should be the same.

Comment: Correspondingly we have $\mathbb{C}^2 / \mathbb{C}^* \cong \mathbb{C}$ via $[u,v] \mapsto u \cdot v$.

Comment: But is it the same of $Spec(\mathbb{C}[x,y])^{\mathbb{C}^*}$?

Comment: No, for example $(x)$ is a prime of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ that is invariant under the $\mathbb{C}^*$ action (since $x$ and $\lambda x$ generate the same ideal) but it doesn't correspond to a prime of the invariant ring.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg - Wait, I'm confused by that. It seems like in $\mathbb{C}^2/\mathbb{C}^*$, $[\lambda,0]$ and $[0,\lambda^{-1}]$ are distinct points, but they have the same image in $\mathbb{C}$ under that map?